# css bootstrap twitter centering spans

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        <h2>Cele mai vandute</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="span10 offset1 well">
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="span2">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </li>
            <li class="span2">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </li>
            <li class="span2">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </li>
            <li class="span2">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </li>
            <li class="span2">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </li>
            <li class="span2">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </li>
            <li class="span2">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </li>
            <li class="span2">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </li>
            <li class="span2">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </li>
            <li class="span2">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hello i'm having trouble in bootstrap css to center this span in a container class.
Can someone explain to me how centering in bootstrap works specially for spans.  thank you very much

Comment: If you are using normal bootstrap then you have too many spans, your amount is totaling 15, when the basic allows for 12. Also your question doesn't make sense, can you explain more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it explained in [bootstrap site](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem).

Normally, your `span`s may sum 12 (until you [customize](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables) it).

Also you are using `<li>` elements instead of `<div>`, which is the element that bootstrap uses for the grid

Some adjusts for your code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span2">
        <h2>Cele mai vandute</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span1">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="span1">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="span1">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="span1">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="span1">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="span1">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="span1">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="span1">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="span1">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="span1">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-src="holder.js/200x100" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i used ul and li instead of div's because on bootstrap website on examples it shows with ul and li.. not with div's

Answer (score 0):

i used ul and li instead of div's because on bootstrap website on examples it shows with ul and li.. not with div's
per one row i can have a total of 12 and after that i need to work on another row again with a max of 12? like this:

```
<div class="row">
<span class="9">...</div>
<span class="3">...</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<span class="9">...</div>
<span class="3">...</div>
```

Comment: Please, use [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). If you have something to add to your question, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) by clicking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14257530/edit). The answers must be just answers.